# Web font @font-face rendering/anti-aliasing in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: font-face, remote-desktop, antialiasing, text-rendering

I'm familiar with the differences in rendering web fonts in different browsers and/or OS. A couple of questions though:

I use a web font (woff) that looks like crap in Chrome but is OK in FF (on Windows 7). The other day I used my office computer from home via remote desktop. I noticed that the font now looked like crap in FF too. It looked much the same as in Chrome at the office. (I didn't test Chrome at home). I know that remote desktop reduces "the graphics" somehow, but not exactly how, and I have no idea how it could effect font rendering. When I came to the office the day after, the rendering in FF was still messed up. I guess the remote desktop session´s changes to "the graphics" was still in effect. I checked with Chrome and now rendering in *that* browser looks fine, like in FF before!!? So I restarted the computer to get back my usual "graphics settings" but that didn't help. Then I cleared the font cache and restarted again. Now I'm back to crappy Chrome rendering and OK FF rendering.

My questions:

1. What is happening with "the graphics" in general, and with font rendering in particular, when I connect with remote desktop (setting = 32-bit color depth)? My guess is that whatever changes, it gets both FF and Chrome to use another rendering method than before.
2. How can the effect still be there after rebooting the computer. Is the "rendering result" somehow stored in the font cache as it seems?? Seems odd.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 7):

Chrome cannot render TrueType fonts with correct anti-aliasing at the moment. WOFF fonts are containers for either OpenType or TrueType, in your case probably TrueType, so you get the crappy rendering. You can either serve an SVG font to Chrome (bigger file size) or use a WOFF based on OpenType.

Apart from that, many other factors influence font rendering, like having the font locally on your system or having ClearType enabled or not (which is not enabled by default through remote desktop).

[See here as well](http://www.vandersterren.com/blog/2012/04/font-linking-chrome-and-anti-aliasing).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and searched but found no answers.

Ultimately in my case it was a combination of remote desktop, server 2012 and browser fonts (Roboto in my case).

It was the worst in chrome, ok in firefox, perfect in ie.

The cause was the missing feature 'desktop experience' in server 2012.

To add this feature to server 2012:

*Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Server Manager. In Server Manager, click Features, and then in the Server Manager details pane, under Features Summary, click Add features. In the Features list, select Desktop Experience, and then click Install.*

That completely fixed the issue for me in all browsers/fonts, hope it helps someone else out there.